# Coding is breaking when port from GCC 3.1.2 to 4.2.2

Tags: c++

```
    // Standard Template Library example
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
// Simple example uses type int
main()
{
    list<int> L;
    L.push_back(0);              // Insert a new element at the end
    L.push_front(0);             // Insert a new element at the beginning
    L.insert(++L.begin(),2);     // Insert "</span><span title="Convert this amount" class="currency_converter_link">2</span><span class="currency_converter_text">" before position of first argument
                                // (Place before second argument)
    L.push_back(5);
    L.push_back(6);

    static list<int>::iterator itr = 0 ;

    if(itr == L.end())
    {
        cout <<"itr is equal to NULL;)" ;
    }
    else 
    {
         cout <<"Not NULL ";
    }


    for(itr=L.begin(); itr != L.end(); ++itr) 
        cout << *itr << " ";

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have about code which is very simple, and throwing a simple error.

```
iterator.cpp:16:29: error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::list<i
nt>::iterator' requested
```

I m quite new to C++, what is best way to deal with this error so that code well compilable.
Just for information, its porting issue when you switch same code from GCC 3.1.2 to 4.2.2.
basically whole question is knitted around one line that is

```
static list<int>::iterator itr = 0 ;
```

as if someone guide me good document to read about these iterators. As old GCC was accepting these things or just throwing warning, but now they are considering this and error.
I am curious that as we assign NUL to pointer and compare against NULL, what is equivalent when it comes to iterator.

Kindly help.
Thanks ...

Comment: I can hear the 'breaking' sound

Comment: Leaving warnings in your code is a good sign that something is wrong. Any warning means the code will probably not be portable. A warning is usually really a logical error (even if it is not a syntactic/semantic error) and you should treat all warnings as errors (and turn the warning level as high as (reasonably) possible)

Comment: Why do you think an iterator should be NULL??? Its an iterator not a pointer (though underneath it may be a pointer this an implementation detail that you should definitely not rely on).

Comment: `main` returns an `int`, C++ has no implicit return types.

Answer (score 2):

Change as follows:

```
   static list<int>::iterator itr = 0 ;
```

to

```
   static list<int>::iterator itr = L.begin() ;
```

BTW, why is this declared as a static local variable?

Comment: +1 for the *why is it static* remark. I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: -1 There is no need to explicitly initialize the iterator (in this code). It's initialized again in the loop. Best just *remove* the explicit initialization (and subsequent `if` check of its effect), as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: It was meant to show how to initialize it to some reasonable default which probably is the beginning of the list (as opposed to using the default constructor of list::iterator)

Comment: I got the meanibg what you are trying to say.
but stil thing is same if it is 
static list<int*>::iterator itr = 0 ; 
As I told I am quite new, wanna be touch with you guys, as I heard somewhere "Watch the master, follow the master, become the master"
If you can direct me to some doc, where I can clarify my about the  how not to use iterator as pointer. becasue an iterator is na iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the explicit initialization (plus, remove the subsequent `if`-`else`).

The initialization `= 0` can work when an iterator is actually a pointer, because a compile time constant integer 0 is then treated as a nullpointer constant.

When the iterator is not of pointer type it has no requirement to support that kind of initialization.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: But it is an iterator. The implementation details of an iterator should not be taken into account (otherwise you are breaking the encapsulation principle).

Comment: @Martin: An iterator is an iterator, yes, and one should not in general rely on implementation details. The first is a meaningless tautology (have you considered the FB Tautology Club?), and the second is a meaningless generalization of what I wrote. In short, what you write is technically meaningless mumbo jumbo, but to a non-technical reader conveys the *impression* of pointing out something.

Comment: @Martin: up until your conclusion you're elaborating on my answer. For example, where I write "has no requirement to support", you write "has no requirement EVER". Then you *imply* that I've written something else. Stop lying. Why are you lying?

Comment: @Martin: thinking about it, one should not necessarily assume evil where other explanations suffice. is it the case that you simply didn't understand that the initialization `= 0` was the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the error:

```
iterator.cpp:16:29: error: conversion from 'int' 
  to non-scalar type 'std::list<i nt>::iterator' requested
```

You're seeing this because you're attempting to initialise an `iterator` to an `int` in this line:

```
static list<int>::iterator itr = 0 ;
```

The compiler doesn't know how to convert an `int` to an `iterator` - hence the error. Not really sure why you have declared the `iterator` as `static` - I see no reason to do so. (That's not a cause of the error, but it makes no sense here.)

Moving on, this code:

```
if(itr == L.end())
{
    cout <<"itr is equal to NULL;)" ;
}
else 
{
     cout <<"Not NULL ";
}
```

...doesn't serve much purpose as far as I'm concerned. You've just initialised your `iterator` with a `0`, so why do you then test it's value?

I recommend getting rid of the `if-else` statement, and initialising the iterator within the scope of the `for` loop instead, like this:

```
int main()
{
    list<int> L;
    L.push_back(0);              
    L.push_front(0);             
    L.insert(++L.begin(),2);     

    L.push_back(5);
    L.push_back(6);

    for(list<int>::iterator itr = L.begin(); itr != L.end(); ++itr) 
       cout << *itr << " ";

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```